# Can we have more than one cfg file in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I am new to hibernate.I have a question please help me.

**Can we have a more than one hibernate.cfg.xml file in one web-app?**

If yes,then please explain.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you want to do? please explain. TIA

Comment: LEo i need to connect two different databases with a single application

Comment: check http://www.javabeat.net/configuring-multiple-databases-in-hibernate/

Comment: It's the same example provided by @Paco Lagunas, please accept his response as the correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Whenever you are creating the session factory, you can specify which configuration file you want to use and create as many SessionFactory objects as needed:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory1 = new  Configuration().configure("ConfigFile_1.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
```

See an example [here](http://www.javabeat.net/configuring-multiple-databases-in-hibernate/)